# Is set of words a regular language?

Tags: automata

Is the set of all words from a regular language A, where every word has a length divided by 2, a regular language?

I was trying to find some counterexample, but without results.

Comment: It is regular. Have you tried to make a DFA to prove it?

Comment: Do you mean the set of those words from a regular language that have even length?  I'm not criticizing your English, just trying to understand.

Comment: yes, sorry for my english

Comment: Ok, I get it. The idea is to link some edges from DFA.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be a regular language on the alphabet $A$. Then the language you consider is the intersection of $L$ with the regular language $(A^2)^*$ of all words of even length. Since the intersection of two regular languages is regular, your language is regular.